# underscore sortBy function doesnt work when number and text are compared

Tags: sorting, underscore.js

sortBy doesnt sort properly. It just returns the array as is.
eg. script that can be run in console directly (provided _ object is available)

```
var abc = ["n/a",0,0,"n/a","n/a",0]
_.sortBy(abc)

//["n/a", 0, 0, "n/a", "n/a", 0]    //returns this
```

any suggestions!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should add an [`iteratee`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) method to enable the function to properly compare values as it sorts. Since you use mixed types (numbers and strings) you need to do some more work.

```
function asNumber(v) {
  var num = Number(v);
  if(isNan(num)) {
    return v; // original value
  } else {
    return num;
  }
}
```

then invoke:

`_.sort(abc, asNumber)`